# Double pole problem in Mellin Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, complex-integration, mellin-transform

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-x/2^k}) \space \Rightarrow \space \frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1},\space(-1<\text{Re}(s)<0)$$ by Mellin Transform, and its asymptotics (as $\space x\to\infty$) by Converse mapping
$$ \log_{2}{x} + \frac{\gamma}{\log2} + \frac{1}{2}+P(x)+O(x^{-1})$$
where P() is a $\Gamma()$ based periodic func(not an issue here)

**I want to know how to get the constant terms, $\frac{\gamma}{\log2} + \frac{1}{2}$.**

There are poles at s = 0(double), pure imaginary(->P(x)) and non-negative integers(don't care, because $\space x\to\infty$, Only Right-sided poles considered)

I got $\log_{2}{x}$ from $\lim_{s\to0} s^2F(s)$, and got $\frac{\gamma}{\log2}$ from $\lim_{s\to0} sF(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{2^s-1} \to \frac{\Gamma'(s+1)}{2^s\log2} = \frac{-\gamma}{\log2}$

**Then, Where the hell does $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?** (shouldn't the constants come only from order $1$ & pole $s = 0$?)

Comment: you do not compute the residue at a double pole correctly as it is the derivative of $s^2F(s)=\frac{s\Gamma(s+1)}{2^s-1} x^{-s}$ at $s=0$ so you get three terms (considering the derivative of $\frac{s}{2^s-1}$ as one such and this last one is $1/2$

Comment: @Conrad // Thank you for your answer. Sorry but, I don't know much about complex analysis so that I did it simply like partial fractions and just  using l'Hopital.  
$$\lim \frac{s^2\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1} = \frac{s\Gamma(s+1)}{2^s-1} \to (l'Hopital) \frac{\Gamma(1)+0\Gamma'(1)}{2^0log2} = \frac{1}{log2}$$
But you mentioned the residue thing, so should I have done closed-contour integral thing?(I don't get why you mentioned 'the derivative')

Could you show me why 3 terms and how to get them a little bit more step by step?

Comment: added a step by step computation as asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you consider $$2\pi if(x)=\int_{c=\Re s}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}x^{-s}ds, -1 < c <0$$ you notice that the integrand goes very fast to zero on any vertical line as $|t| \to \infty$ (except on $\Re s =0$ where $2^s-1$ has zeroes going to infinity too), uniformly for $a \le \Re s \le b$ as long as you stay away from the zeroes of $2^s-1$, so you can use Cauchy on large rectangles with the horizontal part passing through $\pi \log 2 +2\pi k/log 2$ say so $|2^s-1| >> k>0$ there for all $a \le Re s \le b$ to pass to the integral on any line to the right and get

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c=\Re s}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}x^{-s}ds- g(x), c >0$$ arbitrary, where $g(x)$ is given by the residues of the integrand on $\Re s =0$ since the integrand is analytic to the right of $0$

(the minus sign for the residues coming from the fact that the counterclockwise orientation tells us that $\int_{\Re s=b}f(s)ds-\int_{\Re s=a}f(s)=2\pi i$ sum residues in between the vertical lines at $a$ and $b$ when $b>a$)

The residues at $2\pi k/ \log 2, k \ne 0$ are handled as you mentioned, but at $s=0$ we have a double pole so the residue formula requires to take the derivative of $\frac{s^2\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}x^{-s}$ and evaluate it at zero

(for a double pole at zero one has $F(s)=a_2/s^2+ a_1/s+G(s)$ so $s^2F(s)=a_2+a_1s +s^2G(s)$ so $a_1=(s^2F(s))'|_{s=0}$)

Here using $s\Gamma (s)=\Gamma(s+1)$ you get that the residue is the derivative of $\frac{s\Gamma(s+1)}{2^s-1}x^{-s}$ at zero and that derivative has three terms by the usual product rule where we take $(\frac{s}{2^s-1})'$ as one multiplier, the other two coming from $(x^{-s})'$ and $\Gamma'(s+1)$

Since $\frac{s}{2^s-1} \to 1/\log 2, s \to 0$ and $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma, (x^{-s})'|_{s=0}=-\log x$ those last two terms give us indeed residues that are $-\log x/\log 2, -\gamma/\log 2$, respectively (remembering that we subtract the residues when we go from left $-1<c<0$ to right $c>0$ )

The term coming from $(\frac{s}{2^s-1})'=\frac{2^s-1-s2^s \log 2}{(2^s-1)^2}$ converges to $\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{-s2^s (\log 2)^2}{2(2^s-1)\log 2}=-1/2$ and since $\Gamma(1)=1, x^{-0}=1$ we get that extra $1/2$ term mentioned

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation in detail. I think you are right, definitely. Still, I can't understand why I should multiply $x^{-s}$ in the first place, in light of Mellin's Converse Mapping. It cares only f(s), $\frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}$, not attaching $x^{-s}$. It's so confusing to me. Can you explain it with Converse Mapping method-wise?

Comment: where do you get the $\log x$ terms? they come precisely from the derivative of $x^{-s}$ at $0$; see the definition of Mellin transform and its inverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

Comment: You use the definition of the transform to get an inverse function. Yet, there is another way called Converse Mapping. In short, as x approaches infinity, $f(s) = \sum D_{a,k} \frac{1}{(s-a)^k} \to (1:1 \space correspondence) f(x) = \sum -D_{a,k} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}x^{-a}(logx)^{k-1} + O(x^{-r})$

Comment: So, to get the constant terms, (a,k) = (0,1), I simply applied partial fractions & l'Hopital method to the original f(s), not $f(s)x^{-s}$



// to find D(a,k) As for (0,1) -> $lim \space sf(s)$  I got $\frac{-\gamma}{log2}$

As for (0,2), including logx term, ->  $lim \space s^2f(s)$ I got logX/log2. 
as above-mentioned.

Comment: Finally, my original question was how I can find 1/2 from (0,1) with Converse Mapping. or the Mapping doesn't work?(I don't think so.)

Comment: When you have partial fraction of order $2$, so $a/s+b/s^2$ only the leading coefficient $b$ can be found as limit of $s^2f(s)$ but not the coefficient $a$ which is definitely not the limit of $sf(s)$; for that you either take the derivative of $s^2f$ or compute $b$ and take $s(f+(-b)/s^2)$ - the way done in tbe answer is the correct and standard one btw but i guess it should work with partial fractions if computed correctly as then you will get for $a$ precisely the two terms mentioned

Comment: WOW. Thank you again. I finally managed to get it by taking $lim \space s(f(s)-b/s^2)$. I only knew normal partial fractions method except for what you suggested. I've never imagine it that way.  Is it a quite usual way of partial fractions?? Exactly What cases should I use what you suggested like that when applying partial fractions? and WHY?(sorry for keeping asking)

Comment: when you have partial fractions of higher-order then the coefficients can only be found tem by term (or by taking appropriate derivative); in other words if say order is 3 and you have $h(s)=a/s+b/s^2+c/s^3$ you find $c=\lim_{s \to 0} s^3h(s)$ and then either $b=\lim s^2(h-c/s^3)$ etc or $b=(s^3h)'|_{s=0}$ etc

Comment: Thank you. My calculus book(by Stewart) doesn't say that much about partial fractions. Maybe that is because it was not on Complex Analysis.